# Equality up to Swapping

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

### inputs / outputs

your program/function/routine/... will be a predicate on two tuple sequences; call it relation `≡`. for the purpose of simplicity we use natural numbers:

- the input will be two list of pairs of numbers from ℕ (including 0); call them `Xs` and `Ys`
- the output will be a "truthy" value

### specification

`≡` checks the sequences for equality up to permuting elements where the first elements `u` and `u'` don't match.

in other words `≡` compares lists with `(u,v)`s in it for equality. but it doesn't completely care about the order of elements `(u,v)`s. elements can be permuted by swapping; swaps of `(u,v)` and `(u',v')` are only allowed if `u ≠ u'`.

**formally:** write `Xs ≡ Ys` iff `≡` holds for `Xs` and `Ys` as inputs (the predicate is an equivalence relation hence symmetric):

- `[] ≡ []`
- if `rest ≡ rest` then `[(u,v),*rest] ≡ [(u,v),*rest]` (for any `u`, `v`)
- if `u ≠ u'` and `[(u,v),(u',v'),*rest] ≡ Ys` then `[(u',v'),(u,v),*rest] Ys`

### examples

```
[] [] → 1
[] [(0,1)] → 0
[(0,1)] [(0,1)] → 1
[(0,1)] [(1,0)] → 0
[(1,0)] [(1,0)] → 1
[(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,2),(1,3)] → 1
[(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,3),(1,2)] → 0
[(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,2),(1,3),(0,0)] → 0
[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)] [(2,3),(1,2),(0,1)] → 1
[(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)] [(2,3),(1,2),(0,1)] → 0
[(1,2),(0,2),(2,3)] [(2,3),(1,2),(0,1)] → 0
[(1,2),(2,3),(0,2)] [(2,3),(1,2),(0,1)] → 0
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)] → 1
[(3,1),(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,2),(1,3),(3,1)] → 1
[(3,1),(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,3),(1,2),(3,1)] → 0
[(2,1),(3,1),(1,1),(4,1)] [(3,1),(4,1),(1,1)] → 0
[(2,1),(4,1),(3,1),(1,1)] [(3,1),(1,1),(2,1),(4,1)] → 1
[(2,1),(3,1),(1,1),(4,1)] [(3,1),(2,1),(4,1),(1,1)] → 1
```

(keep in mind the relation is symmetric)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges, although this looks like a pretty good first challenge.

Comment: And we are going to call it the "Hamburger menu operator".. More seriously, you have the line `[(0,1)] [(1,0)] → 0` duplicated, did you mean another test case and it's a typo?

Comment: To check that I understand, is this an equivalent way to specify the condtion? "For each number `n`, the pairs whose first element equals `n` within each list come in the same order."

Comment: @Kaddath fixed.

Comment: @xnor: yes, this is equivalent!

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
¤=Ö←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq3Fo@aOmxkdtEx61TdL8f2iJ7eFpQM7///@jo6NjdaJjgRhERxvoGMaCORAWVhFDHQOoCJiFJmIEpA11jKHicB5WWWMwz4iAXh2gzQZIbtCByhlBVRrBzdFBcq0hCSohfGJVGkHdZESk7QgfoYmBVRpjVYnwuzHcTOwqEbYjVBqBVcLUg0gTaNwZw3kQGWT1Jmi6EOohZiBUEWeLEYZdsQA) (header runs function on all test cases)

```
¤       # combin: applies one function to two values and combines the results
 =      # combining function: are they equal?
  Ö←    # function to apply: sort on first element 
        # values (implicit): inputs
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

Assumes that `.sort()` is stable, [which is now guaranteed by the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) (today's version!).

```javascript
a=>b=>(g=a=>a.sort(([a],[b])=>a-b))(a)+''==g(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZPBjoIwEIbvPoW3dmLRtnitx30Cb90eiquoIXQDuMk@PQssDYVYAZUEMjNpP/6Gj6v@0fkhu3wXQWq@juVJlFrsIrHDsagKvc5NVmAstSIyUlBNgggAa1ghJESMIygPJs1NclwnJsZI7rNbcf5VCBbu/ISlgvqG5cxrs1myIUpSwlTNawt4AcUIr47GSPgPdFt4IhVpCdwC68IO76b1pOpQTrbhcAoqvI@yLWkWTEPxBrVtnhbbfoiuJc6yBvsA5e7a9lHuu1gP1WOhz1R@6CT3GTfPEHt06jeOETrLODpunBVkzDg6Xd7aNW9OD@pJeX2p6PtQvD0RfwXl@Q86VDgZNSrvQNsOVf4B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
q=sortOn fst
a%b=q a==q b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPBcoMgFLz7Fe/QzuiEZBByrLce2@kHOByemdg6VUuE3vrtIS8xGrTaJrmwz4V9wK58oPnclqVzRaW/GgvPaHH1Uhgb7BJDxFsNOX3gY5bsABMaMpdjabYGEkjDVDEaOYM4UhGDsKuPbMyAdyzV4lgRyn5Wnhnx56oLQ8iHPeO@A6HoVcLv3ari8R78LpW4nEP8r5KjE87cnlB6KnFWeeoTrntnpc90K1SkAtt8@8H8imR0JX5lUB7jdbzH@nk7JmauMHHwc0yZuJ4yc2Bit/dAcXMUYi6SoMKipkgq1K@gm6K28AApvacfCJFlETwtoY1tsYD2ZSm33@Qlvhu33Gh9AA)

Based on [Arnauld's JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216434/20260). Despite Haskell needing a lengthy import to access sorting, it's well worth the bytes. Note that [sortOn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn), which sorts a list by a custom predicate, is stable. In fact, `sortOn fst` is used for the example in the documentation.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
a%b|let q l=[t|u<-a++b,t<-l,fst t==fst u]=q a==q b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPLjoMgFN33K@5iJtGICUKX8gn9AsPiarTTDG1swV2/fSjWR9HqTKcbzs2Bc4Fz4Av1d6mUtfiZX1Vp4AxKZObapDFGUU5MGitSaQNGiBYaKc6Awg25rVDpUoOALMgkcSMlkIQyJBAMdcsmBOjAupq1lUM@zvKeYb@uejAO6bRnMnZwyEYV83t3qmS@B31LxR7nYH@r@OyEK7d3yD0V61We@o7b0VnuM8MKGcqNuTR@ME@RzK5EXwzKY7yO71i/bsfCzAsmTh7HkonbJTMnJg57TxT/joKtRbI54uHkIjlivYP6cjgZ@ICs/XUQIMlDSGPoYosi6H6WtD9FpXCvbVzU9Q0)

**51 bytes**

```hs
k?l=[x|(i,x)<-l,i==k]
a%b=and[k?a==k?b|(k,_)<-a++b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNBbsMgELz7FXtoJZCxhCHHIL8gL0CoWqdJa5lYVpxKOfjtpaSOHezabZoLu8wyC8zAOzblzlrnyswqfW5Jwc50nVhWKFWaCJ9zhdWrLjP08yxvSclefB3jODduj7bZNaBAE22YHzmDlBrKgPT5BU0Z8B71ubhkPsqhKq@I@HXVDfGRj3umQwcfxcASYe@OlU734A@xxO0c4m@WnJxw4fY@yoAlrqyA/R1Xg7IyRPoVhprodPwIjflhyeRK/E6jAiTo@Ij0y3LMVO4QcfQ45kRczYk5ErHfe8T4txViyZLogEXlLTlgvYH6WFQneALtP1gLBFlOYZ1AZ1scQ/ezjPvc7i2@NS7Z1vUX)

Uses this characterization: For each number `k`, the pairs whose first element equals `k` within each list come in the same order."

The helper function `?` in `k?l` takes a list of pairs `l` and selects for the second element `x` in each pair `(k,x)` with first element equal to `k`. The main function `%` then checks that this is the same on both input lists for each `k` present.

Note that we avoid using sorting, which Haskell doesn't have built-in without a lengthy import.

**51 bytes**

```hs
k?l=[t|t<-l,fst t==k]
a%b=and[k?a==k?b|(k,_)<-a++b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPRboMgFH33K@7DlkjEBLGPEr@gX0DIgl3dGqgxhb357aV0VotOt64vnsuBc4Fz5FMatdfaOVVqxm1ni1Tj2liwjCkRydeKyeadq1L6cVl1scJvqEhlklTC1VKbvQEGPOYC@y/BkCGBMMRDfWUzDGRgfU2vlcd8nM1vDP111Z3xSKY9s7GDRzqqaNi7V2XzPchTKno/B/1blc9OuHJ7j3mgojdVoP7GzehsHjLDCoFEZE9fYTA/IpldiTwYVMAEHZ@xft2OhZkHTJz8HEsmbpbMnJg47D1R/DsKuhZJdJSHxkdylO0W2tOhsfAC3D@wDmKJKwRFCn1sSQL9yxLuvKu1/DAu3bXtBQ)

**51 bytes**

```hs
(?)k=filter$(==k).fst
a%b=and[k?a==k?b|(k,_)<-a++b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPRboMgFH33K@5Dl0DEBqGPJX5Bv8CQBTvdjNQYcW/99jI6q0WnW9cXzs2Bc4Fz4EOZKtfaWpTgShSl7vJ2g4So8LYwXaBeMqHqt7RKlOOS7Iwq8or3kQrDTNpCaZMbEJCiVBI3UgIxlpgAGuorGxOgA@tqdq0c8nGW3xj266o745BOe8ZjB4dsVDG/d6@K53vQp1Tsfg72t4rPTrhye4fcU7GbylN/4250lvvMsEJiGXTtpx/Mj0hmV6IPBuUxXsdnrF@3Y2HmARMnj2PJxN2SmRMTh70nin9HwdYiCU6qrF0kJ9UcoGnLuoMNpO6DnQEpkmHYR9DHFobQ/yxpL8dCq3djo2PTfAE)

**51 bytes**

```hs
l?m=[x|(k,_)<-m,(i,x)<-l,i==k]
a%b|s<-a++b=a?s==b?s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPRboMgFH33K@7DlkDEBKGPEr9gX2DIcm3azYiNKV3Sh377GM5q0enW9YVzc@Bc4Bx4R1vvjHHO5I0qzhdSs1eaJQ0jFTv7wrBKqVpH@FxebJZgHJcKc6tUmVu3R2N3FhQUpNDMj5xBSjVlQIa6Y1MGfGB9LbrKoxxn5ZURv666MR75tGc6dvAoRpUIe/eqdL4Hf0glbucQf6vk7IQrt/coA5W4qgL1N25GZ2XIDCs01dHp@BEG8yOS2ZX4nUEFTNDxEevX7ViYucPEyeNYMnGzZObExGHvieLfUYi1SKIGq4OPpMH2BdpjdTjBExTdvwKCrKSQJdDHFsfQ/yztPrd7g2/WJdu2/QI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.sort_by{_1[0]}==b.sort_by{_1[0]}}
```

No TIO link, as TIO uses an older version of Ruby.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.sort_by(&:first)==b.sort_by(&:first)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6Ua84v6gkPqlSQ80qLbOouETT1jYJQ6z2f0FpSbGCUkhQaIhHJBeXEhdXgUJadHSsTnRsLIQZbaBjGAvkQ2iYoKGOAVgQTCMEjYBihjrGUCk4D9koHaiEEVQZiIaJoVmBUIwwE00MptgYq2IYTwcsD1dsBFZsAiZhGiF@RPB0kFShaURWZIKiEdlgQ4hGLkgAc7k5@gS7ooYwqndhwYw3RGFBRTDIQWFpgD0siQh4iBAJio2gVhrhV4w9lhCKjUkJbORg/g8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{~/x@'<'*''x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BDgIhDEX3noIdYDQDhZV14WnGhcmsJzF6dWwLAwYnuCD09/3f9nFe7ktK8@X5ntabvuqj1usrzeZkLNKzh1I65aWmvxNeORH0V2G8AvQqWKzVTztQBXbfjY7mCOIV3ATBkFPIB5TkH8xiiEG2wWj4dlpTgkOH8@VhS/c4D68YCGeLx0hNlEDMnWaJzVYsHChkNAm@p6X0AQ)

Takes input as a single argument of two lists of lists.

- `x@'<'*''x` sort each input by the first item of each-each input
- `~/` do the two sorted lists match?

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
⬤⁺θη⁼Φθ⁼§λ⁰§ι⁰Φη⁼§λ⁰§ι⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMxJ0cjIKe0WKNQRyFDU0fBtbA0MadYwy0zpyS1CCQIFXAs8cxLSa3QyNFRMAAqg3EzQVxNoABUQwaRGoDA@v//6OhoYx3DWJ1oQx0jMGkcC6SQeDpg@djY/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for equivalent, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
  θ                     First list
 ⁺                      Concatenated with
   η                    Second list
⬤                       All pairs must satisfy
      θ                 First list
     Φ                  Filtered where
        §λ⁰             First element of inner pair
       ⁼                Equals
           §ι⁰          First element of outer pair
    ⁼                   Equals
               η        Second list
              Φ         Filtered where
                 §λ⁰    First element of inner pair
                ⁼       Equals
                    §ι⁰ First element of outer pair
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 21 bytes

```
%O#`\d+,\d+
^(.+)¶\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg8F/VXzkhJkVbB4i54jT0tDUPbYsxVPn/PzpWITqWC0RqGOgYagKZEBoL31DHAMwH0yh8I00dIGkMFYXzsMgZg3lGePXpAG00gNusA5UxgqozgpuhA3ehIdHqIDzi1BlB3WJElL0If6CJAdUZY1WH8K8x1Dzs6hD2wtQZgdXBVINIE2gcGcN5EBmEahM0PQjVEBMQqoixwQjdHgA) Assumes lists on separate lines but link includes header that splits the test cases for ease of use. Explanation:

```
%O#`\d+,\d+
```

Sort each list stably by the first element of each pair.

```
^(.+)¶\1$
```

Compare the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṖÞ€E
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of the two lists which yields `1` (truthy) or `0` (falsey).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmmH5z1qWuP6////6GgNQx0jTR0gaawZq8OlEA1m6YBFY7liAQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmmH5z1qWuP6/@HuLUf3PNyxKQzIO9x@rAtIqWQBiUcNcxR07RQeNcyN/P8/OlYhOpYLREYb6BjGApkQGgvfUMcAzAfTKHyjWB0gaQwVhfOwyBmDeUZ49ekAbTSA26wDlTGCqjOCm6EDd6Eh0eogPOLUGUHdYkSUvQh/oIkB1RljVYfwrzHUPOzqEPbC1BmB1cFUg0gTaBwZw3kQGYRqEzQ9CNUQExCqiLHBCN0eAA).

#### How?

```
ṖÞ€E - Link: [a,b]
  €  - for each list, [t_1, t_2, ...], in [a,b]
 Þ   -   sort by:
Ṗ    -     pop (t_n with its tail removed)
   E - all equal?
```